# Best practice to initialize jQuery plugins in Wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress, initialization

What will be the best way to initialize jQuery plugins in a theme

I have two options:

1. to create a separate file and including it using `wp_enqueue_script`
2. directly on page using

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
             $('.div').isotope();
         });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

"to create a separate file and including it using `wp_enqueue_script` method" is proper.

In `wp_enqueue_script` you can specify that this script depends on jQuery, so WordPress load jQuery first if it is not included and then add your script.

```
function theme_name_scripts() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'script-name', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', 
        array('jquery'), 
        '1.0.0', 
        true 
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Your code will be in your-script.js  file.